# POSTMAN - AMAZON MWS - SubmitFeed - the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match

Tags: post, file-upload, postman, amazon-mws, web-api-testing

I am trying to use [SubmitFeed](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html) web service to upload products to Amazon via `POSTMAN` application.

I tested my request using `Amazon MWS Scratchpad` and it works. However when I try to do the same request from `POSTMAN`, I receive `ContentMD5DoesNotMatch` error.

MD5 value I calculate and MD5 value `Amazon MWS Scratchpad` is same. For that reason I believe there is some issues while I upload the file.

What am I missing?

This is file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_EXAMPLE_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>56789</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>ASIN</Type>
        <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
        <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
        <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
        <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
        <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
        <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
        <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Health>
          <ProductType>
            <HealthMisc>
              <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
              <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
            </HealthMisc>
          </ProductType>
        </Health>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

**This is body of my request and response:**

[image]

This is my Pre-request-script:

```
var HTTPVerb = "POST";
var ValueOfHostHeaderInLowercase = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com"; 
var HTTPRequestURI = "/";

var TimeStamp = encodeURIComponent(new Date().toISOString());

var ContentMD5Value = "7iiKpIWEgdex10Isb8Szrw=="; //I wrote it here hardcoded here, to be sure.

var CanonicalizedQueryString = 
"AWSAccessKeyId=" + "***" +
"&Action=" + "SubmitFeed" +
"&ContentMD5Value=" + encodeURIComponent(ContentMD5Value) +
"&FeedType=" + "_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_" +
"&MWSAuthToken=" + "***" +
"&MarketplaceIdList.Id.1=" + "***" +
"&Merchant=" + "***" +
"&PurgeAndReplace=" + "false" + 
"&SignatureMethod=" + "HmacSHA256" +
"&SignatureVersion=" + "2" +
"&Timestamp=" + TimeStamp +
"&Version=" + "2009-01-01";

var StringToSign = HTTPVerb + "\n" +
  "mws-eu.amazonservices.com" + "\n" +
  HTTPRequestURI + "\n" +
  CanonicalizedQueryString;

let hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(StringToSign, '***');
let Signature = (CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash));

var PostQueryString = 
"AWSAccessKeyId=" + "***" +
"&Action=" + "SubmitFeed" +
"&Merchant=" + "***" +
"&MWSAuthToken=" + "***" +
"&SignatureVersion=" + "2" +
"&Timestamp=" + TimeStamp +
"&Version=" + "2009-01-01" +
"&ContentMD5Value=" + encodeURIComponent(ContentMD5Value) +
"&Signature=" + encodeURIComponent(Signature) + 
"&SignatureMethod=" + "HmacSHA256" +
"&FeedType=" + "_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_" +
"&MarketplaceIdList.Id.1=" + "***" +
"&PurgeAndReplace=" + "false"
;

pm.environment.set('AmazonHost', ValueOfHostHeaderInLowercase + HTTPRequestURI + '?' + PostQueryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well we cannot be sure of the problem that you're getting but most of the time when I get this problem is because of missing parameters or having undefined or empty values in some of the parameters like `FeedType`.

I print my Canonicized string in the program and compare it with `String to Sign` in the request details of mws-scratchpad.

Comment: I already created my string by checking mws-scartchpad,  Are you using postman for your requests?

Comment: I have an api written in node js. I am calling that api with nodejs, not directly mws.

Comment: I hardcoded the MD5 value in my script, so it is not possible much that it is parameter related, it is possibly a postman setting that I am missing.

Comment: Okay, I see you've included ContentMD5 value in your canonicized string. We don't include it in our Canonicized string. See here http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_QueryString.html

Comment: It's a required field, I am not sure how do you work without including it. If I remove it, this is the response from amazon: "you must pass a Content-MD5 HTTP header for your feed so we can be sure it was not corrupted (e.g. dropped a 0 from a price) before we process it"

Comment: Oh. I missed it. Just saw in the documentation that we require Md5ContentValue in SubmitFeed. However, there is also another thing that you're URIEncoding MD5 and Signature in POST query string which is not required in my opinion.

Comment: If I remove URIEncoding, then since my MD5 value contains = character, the response from amazon turns into this: "Invalid query string provided, query string is not valid, the value of a query string parameter may not contain a &apos;=&apos; delimiter".